# Getting dependencies in a Python development environment

Tags: python, dependencies, build-process

When working with JVM languages a pattern commonly followed is to use a build system (ant+ivy / maven / gradle), where using a build file, the dependencies of your code can be defined. The build system is able to fetch these dependencies when you build your code. Moreover IDEs like Eclipse/IntelliJ are also able to read these build files and continuously build/verify your code as you write it.

How is something similar done while developing in Python? While there may not necessarily be a build step, I want a developer to be able to checkout my code and then run a single bootstrap command that will setup a virtualenv and pull in any thirdy-party dependencies necessary to run the code. I could include some sort of a script to do this, but I am wondering if there is a tool to do this? Most of my search so far has led me to packaging tools, which are more for distribution to end-user than for this purpose (or so I understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is managed by [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command. More info here: [Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: Thanks! I found some more related useful links - 
http://www.pindi.us/blog/automating-pip-and-virtualenv-shell-scripts,
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files,
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format,
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers,
and http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/#personal-pypi

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for adding those links as they may help others that find your question, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) is what you are looking for. For example, PyCharm IDE will definitely see it as a dependency list.